# How to make WKWebView to render the content only when all of it is loaded?

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview

Hi there,

I'm using a `WKWebView` in my app and when I load a web page, the web page is rendered progressively ( typically : first I can see the text and then the images are loaded ).
What I'd like to do, is to display the web page only when all the content is loaded.

Is there a way to configure a `WKWebView` so it only displays content that's completely loaded ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `suppressesIncrementalRendering` property on the WKWebView's `configuration` object.

`webView.configuration.suppressesIncrementalRendering = true`